# Replace method names with lower first char

Tags: c#, regex

need some help.
Wanna replace all method names in code with rule:

```
MethodName -> methodName (need for cpp translation).
```

Unfortunatelly, I need to escape in my Regex all cases that started with `new`.

My regex:

```
 `[>\\.\\s]+[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\\({1}`
```

It matches to

```
`>MethodName(`, `.MethodName(` ` MethodName(`
```

but also in last case can be `new ClassName`.

How to avoid this case?

Comment: Resharper allows you to define your Naming Style. Set "Methods properties and events" to `lowerCamelCase` and have Resharper do the clean-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<!new)[>.\s]+[A-Z]+\w*\(
```

`(?<!new)` is a negative lookbehind, it will ensure that the method name is not preceded by the keyword `new`.

I also:

- changed `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` to `\w` since it's equivalent;
- remove the quantifier `{1}` which was redundant.

Comment: I agree with your changes. You could also remove the redundant `+` in `[A-Z]+\w*`

Comment: Many thanks, guys, it works) About quantifier {1}: I think it's not redundant according to case `SomeMethod().SomeMethod2()`. But anyway anything else is good.

Comment: @ArgorAvest `{1}` is implicit, `a` == `a{1}`

Comment: @BrianStephens yep, `+` was also redundant. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to find with leading space? If not:

- First character may by > or .
- Followed by capital letter
- Follwed by zero or more letter,number or underline
- Followed by (

  `[>|\.]([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_])*\(`